# How to promote a fixup commit to a regular commit in Git?

Tags: git, version-control

I have created a fixup commit with code that I now realized should be a regular commit. I don't want to have any surprises on the next rebase - how can I make this fixup commit a regular commit, dis-associating it from the commit ID I tried to "fix"?

Comment: The only association in a fixup commit is its commit message. So use interactive rebase to re-word the message and you are done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A fixup commit (that is, one you create with `git commit --fixup`) or a squash commit (one you create with `git commit --squash`) are really just regular commits.  So if you'd like to turn one of them into a regular commit, just edit its commit message.

- if the commit is the latest in the branch, use `git commit --amend`,
- if it's earlier, you can use `git rebase -i` (without the `--autosquash` option) to edit the commit message and place it where you'd like it.